# Angular 1.5 - Ui-Router 1.0.0-beta.3 - No template configuration specified for 'resolve@root''

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I'm trying to get UI-Router's resolve method to work but I keep getting this error and I have not been successful in resolving this issue. `Error: No template configuration specified for 'resolve@root'`

Here's my stateProvider's definition:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('root', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
      'header@': {
        template: '<div>Header</div>',
      },
      'footer@': {
        template: '<div>Footer</div>',
      }
    }
  })

.state('root.home', {
  views: {
    'home@': {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'src/survey/survey.template.html',
      controller: 'homeController'
    },
    resolve: {
        communityId: ['backendFactoryService', function (backendFactoryService) {
            backendFactoryService....then(function (res) {
                return res;
            })
        }],
        brandingId: ['backendFactoryService', function (backendFactoryService) {
            // do stuff
            })
        }],
        community: ['backendFactoryService', function (backendFactoryService) {
                   // do stuff 
            })
        }],
        branding: ['backendFactoryService', function (backendFactoryService) {

                   // do stuff
            })
        }]
    }
  }
})
```

In my home.controller.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict'

  angular.module('someModule')
    .controller('homeController', homeController)

  homeController.$inject = [
    '$scope',
    'branding',
    'brandingId',
    'community',
    'communityId'
  ];

  function homeController(
    $scope,
    branding,
    brandingId,
    community,
    communityId
  ) {
    $scope.community = community;
    $scope.branding = branding;
    $scope.brandingId = brandingId;
    $scope.communityId = communityId;
  }
})();
```

Clearly I have a templateUrl for the controller and resolve block. I tried adding an empty `<div ui-view=""></div>` or `<ui-view></ui-view>` for my root state, but nothing.
I can't find an answer for the error I'm getting, hopefully someone can help me here.

EDIT:

I have also tried to add a `template: ' '` in my `root` state. No difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is because of

```
resolve: {
    communityId: ['backendFactoryService', function (backendFactoryService) {
        backendFactoryService....then(function (res) {
            return res;
        })
    }],
    brandingId: ['backendFactoryService', function (backendFactoryService) {
        // do stuff
        })
    }],
    community: ['backendFactoryService', function (backendFactoryService) {
               // do stuff 
        })
    }],
    branding: ['backendFactoryService', function (backendFactoryService) {

               // do stuff
        })
    }]
}
```

as it is thinking that `resolve` is view name and it is checking for template, controller etc.

So change your state config code to

```
.state('root.home', {
  resolve: {
    communityId: ['backendFactoryService', function (backendFactoryService) {
        backendFactoryService....then(function (res) {
            return res;
        })
    }],
    brandingId: ['backendFactoryService', function (backendFactoryService) {
        // do stuff
        })
    }],
    community: ['backendFactoryService', function (backendFactoryService) {
               // do stuff 
        })
    }],
    branding: ['backendFactoryService', function (backendFactoryService) {

               // do stuff
        })
    }]
  },
  views: {
    'home@': {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'src/survey/survey.template.html',
      controller: 'homeController',        
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: ah silly mistake, I was making the resolve a separate object outside of the views. Thank you @Mr_Perfect

Comment: I know it's outside of the scope of this question, but now when I inject those variables (i.e. branding, community etc..) in my controller I get an `Error: [$injector:unpr]` as well, this shouldn't be right?

Comment: Change `['backendFactoryService', function (backendFactoryService) {

                   // do stuff
            })
        }]` to `function (backendFactoryService) {

                   // do stuff
      
        }`. No need to inject in array format. Services are available to `resolve` property. Let me know if it works

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix the problem, could this be something to with ui-router itself. as I'm using their beta version. I know I spent hours trying to figure out why their `component` wasn't working until I came to an a github issue saying that it wasn't yet implemented, it was in beta =|

Comment: I edited the answer.  `resolve` *is not a property of a view*.  See the docs for [what can go on a view](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/ng1.ng1viewdeclaration.html) .  `resolve` [belongs on a state declaration](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/ng1.ng1statedeclaration.html#resolve)